# In google colab I enable GPU but it isn't used

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu, google-colaboratory

I enable GPU by going to >>runtime>> change runtime type >> then choose GPU.
But when I run my code I get this error:

```
usage: train.py [-h] [--pre PRETRAINED] TRAIN TEST GPU TASK
train.py: error: the following arguments are required: GPU, TASK
```

this is the part of the code that make error:

! python train.py part_A_train.json part_A_val.json

I also have this warning:

```
Warning: You are connected to a GPU runtime, but not utilising the GPU.
```

but by running this code looks like that GPU is active!

[image]

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the piece of code related to the generated error?  What I want to understand from it is: that `error: the following arguments are required: GPU, TASK` is printed because you are missing some of the requirements or because you made a mistake in the arguments while calling `train.py`?

Comment: @claudia I add the picture of code. I don't still find the answer. I appreciate it if you know help guide me.

Comment: I meant the code inside train.py, otherwise it's really hard to understand what's going on. Also please add the code as text, not images. Thanks